# Get rank from MySQL table into TextView

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql

I have an Android application which should get the current rank of an user based on his earned points and set it in defined textview "txtRank".

These values are stored in MySQL. When I execute the code I always get rank as null, but when I execute just the SQL-Statement on PHPMYADMIN it gives me the correct resutl.

Any ideas?

Here the PHP:

```
$uname = $_POST['uname'];

        $sql1       =  "SET @rownum := 0";

        $sql2       =   "SELECT rank, points FROM (
                        SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, points, uname
                        FROM points ORDER BY points DESC
                        ) as result WHERE uname=$uname";

        mysql_query($sql1); 
        $result = mysql_query($sql2);
        $rows = '';
        $data = array();
        if (!empty($result))
            $rows      =  mysql_num_rows($result);
        else
            $rows      =  '';

        if (!empty($rows)){
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $data[]   = $rows;
            }
        }

        if ($sql2){
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["user"]["rank"] = $data[0]['rank'];
            echo json_encode($response);

        }else{  

            $response["error"]     = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Something went wrong";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

Here the AsynchTask and setText Method:

```
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_RANK = "rank";
....

private class GetRank extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        String uname;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

            // Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

            user = db.getUserDetails();
            uname = user.get("uname");

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

            JSONObject json = userFunction.getUserdata(uname);

            return json;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            /**
             * Checks for success message.
             **/
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {


                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        setTextRank(json_user.getString(KEY_RANK));


                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(red) == 1) {

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Noch kein Bild!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER
                                | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();

                    }

                    else {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Fehler aufgetreten, bitte nochmal versuchen",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

    public void setTextRank(String text) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtRank);
            textView.setText(text);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the variables correctly to sql.

You should concatenate string, e.g:

```
$rownum     =mysql_query($sql1);
$sql2       =   "SELECT rank, points FROM (
                 SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1  AS rank, points, uname
                FROM points ORDER BY points DESC
                ) as result WHERE uname=".$uname;
```

(I am not sure if syntax for rownum would work).
However, this is not the safe way.

Comment: tried it and now I get an `Undefined Offsett: 0 Error` on line `if ($sql2){
   $response["success"] = 1;
   $response["user"]["rank"] = [$data[0]['rank']];
   echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: I updated the answer. Are you sure that `if ($sql2)` is correct condition? `$sql2` is a `string`.

Comment: ok you're right I changed it to `if($result`) to check if the sql is executed. It seems that the sql will not be executed because I get the second `case ("something went wrong")`. I have the php code from here: [link](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/). hm weird